# How to write the timestamp when exporting to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, timestamp

I want to add timestamp (DD-MM-YYYY h:m:s) every time I write data to a CSV file.
This is my code:

```
def WriteListtoCSV(data):
    with open ('tesdata.csv','a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for val in data:
                writer.writerow([val])
```

In every write row I want to write TimeStamp in column 1 and data in column 2.

Comment: unrelated: use YYYY-MM-DD format so that if you sort the lines as strings; they would be sorted by time too (for free).

Answer (score 3):

The [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module will give you the current system time, and it supports a [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) method where you format the time per your requirement ('DD-MM-YYY h:m:s').

```
import time

for val in data:
    now = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    writer.writerow([now, val])
```

Comment: @ImamAbdulMahmudi: you could also use `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z (%Z)')`, to get the time string directly without an intermediate datetime object.